# console functions saved to variable in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, console

This seems to happen only chrome, wondering if anyone know why it happens or how to fix it.

doing `console.log('test')` print out 'test'

now if we save the function

```
var log = console.log
log('test')
```

this gives us TypeError: Illegal invocation

same thing happens with all the methods of console, like error and warn

Comment: Two words: `missing context`. Three more: `to the method`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console);
log('test');
```

With `.bind` you'll provide `console` with the correct context (i.e. itself) to operate.

Comment: Why isn't `console.log` prebound for us?

Comment: Not sure, would certainly make sense.

Comment: ya I am wondering about that too, why does it loss the context

Comment: @AbrahamAdam that's how JS works: all methods, unless specifically bound, lose their context if you 'detach' them from their instance.

Comment: Alternatively, try `log.call(console, "test")`

Comment: ah makes sense sorry for stupid question lol, guess I just got used to it working in order browsers